# React JS Cookie Banner UI

Tags: css, reactjs, cookies

Hello I am trying to make a cookie banner using React JS. I tried using paddings and alignment but was unable to meet the requirement. May you please help me and what to add with my inline-styline

I downloaded the NPM: `npm i react-cookie-consent`

```
import CookieConsent, { Cookies } from "react-cookie-consent";

    <CookieConsent
      location="bottom"
      buttonText="Yes, I agree"
      cookieName="GLA"
      style={{ background: "#262626" }}
      buttonStyle={{ justifyContent: "left", background: "#3f7edf", color: "#FFFFFF", fontSize: "13px" }}
      expires={150}
    >

      <p styles={{ textAlign: "center", color: "#FFFFFF", fontSize: "24px" }}>We use cookies on this site to enhance your user experience</p>

      <p styles={{ textAlign: "center", color: "#FFFFFF" }}> By clicking any link on this page you are giving your consent for us to set cookies. Detailed information, also on the right to withdraw consent, can be found in the <a href="/" target="_blank" rel="noreferrer">website's privacy policy.</a></p>
    </CookieConsent>
```

Current Design:

[image]

Here is my goal and expecting result:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

try to add this in your style
style={{background: "#262626", maxWidth:"1200px", display:"flex", justifyContent:"center", alignItems:"flex-end"}}